# How to use Generic type when implementing ReduceFunction

Tags: java, apache-flink

Trying to implement a ReduceFunction which is as able to accept any generic that extends a class called KeyedMetricDTO. I cannot figure out how to do this correctly.. i currently have a working example using Object as the type, but I don't think this is the best practice

```
public class MostRecentElementReducer<T extends KeyedMetricDTO> implements ReduceFunction {
    @Override
    public Object reduce(Object value1, Object value2) throws Exception {
        return value2;
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to change Object to something like `<T extends KeyedMetricDTO`, my IDE tells me that
`Class 'MostRecentElementReducer' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'reduce(T, T)' in 'ReduceFunction'`

How do I correctly declare the types for this?

Additional Information which could be useful.. when I call this reduce function

```
            return stream
                    .reduce(new MostRecentElementReducer(), getProcessor())
                    .name(String.format("%s_AlarmReducer", getType()))
                    .uid(String.format("%s_alarmReducer_id", getType()));
```

I get this warning

````
Unchecked assignment: 'org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.SingleOutputStreamOperator' to 'org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream<io.halter.device.metrics.monitoring.model.alarm.Alarm>'. Reason: 'stream .reduce(new MostRecentElementReducer(), getProcessor()) .name(String.format("%s_AlarmReducer", getType()))' has raw type, so result of uid is erased ```
````

Comment: `public KeyedMetricDTO reduce(KeyedMetricDTO value1, KeyedMetricDTO value2)`? but that is a weird way to reduce anyway, you always return `value2`

Comment: The goal is to only keep the most recent element in the window. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: that will only work if the the "source" of your stream is `ordered`. or better find a way to compare two `KeyedMetricDTO` and take the "most recent one"

Comment: Yeah that is a good call